# Clever way to iterate over all query results with the same attribute

Tags: python, django

Assume:

```
class ItemToBill(models.Model):
    date_to_bill = fields.DateField()
    description = fields.charfield()
    customerToBill = fields.ForeignKey(Customer)
```

I want to find all items that should be billed before today, and then group them by customer so I can create a single invoice for each customer that needs it.

```
for unique_customer in all_unique_customers_with_items_to_bill:
    createInvoice(unique_customer,  their_items_to_bill)
```

I could probably do something where I query the items (ordering by the customers) and then identifying when I've entered a new customer's set of items.  This would look like:

```
items = ItemToBill.objects.filter(date_to_bill=BEFORE_TODAY).order_by(customer)
prevCustomer = items[0].customer
customer_items = []
for item in items:
    if prevCustomer != item.customer:
        createInvoice(prevCustomer, customer_items)
        customer_items = []
        prevCustomer = item.customer
    customer_items.append(item)
createInvioce(prevCustomer, customer_items) #Handle the last customer
```

but there's got to be a more clever solution.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a list of items by customer, which sounds like a simple loop.

```
items_by_customer = {}

for item in ItemToBill.objects.filter(...date_query...):
    items_by_customer.setdefault(item.customerToBill, []).append(item)

for customer, items in items_by_customer.items():
    print customer, items # items grouped by customer.
    # generate_invoice(customer, items)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably first aggregate all records for each customer into a dictionary:

```
from collections import defaultdict
items = ItemToBill.objects.filter(date_to_bill=BEFORE_TODAY).order_by(customer)
bills_by_customer = defaultdict(list)
for bill in items:
    bills_by_customer[bill.customer.pk].append(bill)
```

Then you can iterate over the grouped dictionary:

```
for customer_pk, bills in bills_by_customer.iteritems():
    createInvoice(customer_pk, bills)
```